# Two adapters communicating on same subnet

Tags: networking, ip, tcp, udp

I have two sensors that each provide approximately 1Gbps of data and have static IPs on the same subnet. I have one PC with two 1xGbps adapters that I am using for processing the incoming data (OS is Ubuntu). There is also an internal network of other machines that must be communicated with on the same subnet. I thought that if I connected one sensor two one adapter on the processing computer and then connected the other sensor to a switch connected to the internal network with another connection to the other adapter on my processing PC that I would be able to communicate with both sensors. I have since read that this is not the case out of the box.

I cannot change the IP addresses of the sensors due to the manufacturer settings and need to process then in the same machine. Is there anyway to tell Ubuntu that only one IP address in the subnet is out one adapter and the rest is out the other?

[network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHByf.png)

Comment: Is the cloud in your diagram meant to signify the internet? If so, are you saying that you connect to one sensor on the local network and connect to the other sensor over the internet?

Comment: What equipment do you use in the `192.168.1.255`  cloud? 192.168.1.255 is broadcast address, network address is 192.168.1.0/24.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the ".15" NIC as you would normally (I'm guessing 192.168.1.15/24, etc.,) then route that one specific address through the other interface (let's call it `eth1` for example's sake):

```
ip route add 192.168.1.21/32 dev eth1
```